# Ошибка в подключении файла из другой папки

Tags: php, route

произошла ошибка в подключении файла. В папке с доменом (localhost) есть папка **vid**, в которой указаны  компоненты сайта(**components, views**). В папке **views** лежит файл **index.php**, пример вставленного кода оттуда. В другой папке, components лежит класс **Router.php**. В этом классе есть простейшая функция echo для проверки его работоспособности(в **index.php** я даже не могу создать объект этого класса)  Так вот, при подключении файла **Router.php** из файла **index.php** возникает ошибка, текст ошибки полностью показан на скриншоте. Как решить эту проблему? Как нужно правильно указать пути в коде, приведённом ниже? Прошу помощи.[image: Ошибка при открытии файла Router.php]

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Router.php');
```

Comment: Регистр в именах файлов верный?

Comment: @MAX Да, регистр верный. Имена папок тоже проверял, всё верно.

Comment: Ну ошибка однозначная — файл не найден. Иногда путают букву «c» русскую/английскую. Особенно когда она первая, как у вас.

Comment: @MAX К сожалению, проблема не в этом :( Скорее всего путь указан неправильно

Comment: Ну так реальный путь у вас в ошибке приведен. Его в первую очередь проверить нужно. :)